# pdfusetitle uses the short title while it could have used the long one

Tags: hyperref, titles

Consider the following document

```
\documentclass{amsart}
    \usepackage{lipsum}
    \usepackage[pdfusetitle]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

    \title[Short]{Long Title}
    \maketitle
    \lipsum[1-13]

\end{document}
```

Usually, `amsart` puts your title at the top of every odd page.
When the title is too long, the header bleeds
so it is natural to add a short title.
However, `hyperref` decides to include the short one in the metadata of the PDF file.
I guess that `hyperref` expects users to input a PDF-save short title
while the long one is not PDF-save.

But that means the short title now serves two purposes,
one for avoiding a long title and one for avoiding not PDF-save tokens.
What to you think is the proper way to resolve this.

Short question: can I make `hyperref` add the long title into PDF's metadata?
Is `pdftitle=\@title` a proper one?

Comment: Maybe `\title[\texorpdfstring{Short}{Long Title}]{Long Title}` does what you want?

Comment: Make sense if I have three titles.